# how to make webmethod parameters mandatory

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I would like to make few of the parameters of my webmethods to be mandatory.

I tried to use XmlElement as below

```
@XmlElement(required=true) @WebParam(name = "orderReference") String orderReference
```

I have copied jaxws-api-2.2.jar into jdk-jre-lib as well, still my wsdl snippets shows

and in soapUI its been displayed as "optional".

how do I make this parameter as mandatory ? Have I missed anything?

Comment: I found that required=true is a bit of a black art in jaxws. Try putting it on your setter if it is currently on the field. I found that the combination of getters/setters and annotations on the field itself often caused oddities in my wsdl.

Comment: thanks for the response, i dont have any getter/setters to my parameters. They are coming from another system and I am using them in my webmethods and I want to make them mandatory.